# Chart isnt centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, charts

When my chart doesnt have any data loaded in it's perfectly centered and contained withing it's element, but when the chart has data the chart gets pushed to the right and becomes smaller

My options for the chart:

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    barRoundness: 1,
    scaleShowValues: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          barThickness: 6,
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            fontSize: 9
          },
          gridLines: { display: false }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: false, gridLines: { display: false } }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
```

Where I implement it:

```
<div v-if="loadedMatch" class="graph mt-2 rounded">
    <newgraph :width="327" :height="312" :bets="this.betsForMatch"
    v-if="loadedBets"
    v-on:barInteracted="onBarInteracted"/>
</div>
```

[image: The result]

I want the chart to fill the entire white space

Im using the vue-chart.js version of Chart.js. Sorry if im not providing enough information from the start.

Answer (score 0):

It was the labels for the x-axis ticks that made the chart go to the left. So i need to fick the x-axis ticks